# How to visualize vtk data set with only point data

Tags: c++, visualization, vtk

I have a vtk dataset with only point data but no cell data. I would like to visualize the dataset as point cloud. When I read the dataset as polyData it wouldn’t show anything on the screen. One work around I did was first writing the dataset as .xyz files, then read from the .xyz files and visualize. Another way I came up with is inserting the points as vertices manually.

Are there any neater ways to achieve this goal?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You may check out the vtkVertexGlyphFilter class:

https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkVertexGlyphFilter.html

Comment: And here is the official example: https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Cxx/Filtering/VertexGlyphFilter/